# Is it possible to pre-run a “simulation” in Unity (turn real time off) convergence study

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am doing an Unity C# project. For this I have a physics engine implemented, that models behaviour that I want to simulate correctly. This (not by unity) implemented physics is updated once ever \delta t (Hereford I use the fixed update). Now I want to do a convergence study in order to see how low the time step needs to be, in order to correctly simulate the wanted behaviour. (Solving the PDE needs quiet small times steps in this case). Therefore I want to run a reference simulation for a very small time step and then compare all other solutions to this time step.

Now I have the issue, that for small times steps, the simulation just lags/ doesn’t really start, I guess because it takes more time to calculate each update than the time step is long. Therefore I am wondering, if it is possible to pre-calculate this or turn the real time updating off? So the goal would be to once do this simulation, so it would be fine, if the computer takes quiet some time to calculate it and then just gives me the results.
thank you very much!

Comment: How exactly is your simulation built that it depends on Unity? Can't you just run the simulation on its own (in a loop or something similar) to get the results you need?

Comment: @UnholySheep unfortounaly i can’t run it on its own, as I depend on the build in Unity collision detection. Therefore  I have to run it in the normal Unity game engine.

Comment: @shingo no unfortunately I don’t think so. The rendering process is not what takes up most calculation power (it’s 99+% the constraint solving of the implemented physics). Therefore I want to calculate this beforehand if possible.

Comment: Haven't you read my answer? It's about how to turn the real time updating off.

Comment: Sorry, Then I might understand your answer wrong. I still need it so simulate how it would behave in real time, but it is not necessary to compute it in real time. I understood from your answer: “The physical process and rendering process are independent of each other, you can call the Physics.Simulate method many times in a single frame.” That I call the physics update many times a frame, but that doesn’t matter, as the Programm won’t run. I did unfortunately not get from your answer how to make these independent from each other as you stated it to be possible. Thanks